# How do you get the gold key from the Osmos-like area?

Tags: botanicula

I'm trying to get the key from the Osmos-like (bunch of round things swimming around in a nodule) screen, and my little flying dude keeps getting knocked back. I've tried jamming the small 1-2-3 marked blobs into the holes that puff the windmill guy back to no avail.  How do I get said key?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use the red cell to knock the key down you go through the one that is one hole behind the first 2 times. and the final time use the first hole.

Comment: Got it; controlling the red cell is a pain in the ass; is the only thing you can do to influence it whip your cursor across it?  Welcome to the site, btw :P

Comment: @Nick The red ball is meant to be directly controllable but there's a bug that makes it uncontrollable if your window size is set to 100% - try setting it to 60% and it should be much easier!

Comment: @Neil, I wish I'd known that beforehand.  This took me an age to get past at 100%!

Answer (score 6):

**Push the red thing through three different holes until you knock the key to the ground.** It's much easier to control at a smaller screen size (e.g., 60% or even 100% windowed).

[image: gold key]