# Where can I find the keys in level 2?

Tags: botanicula

I'm stuck and can't move forward because I'm missing one of the keys. I've been all over every possible branch several times! Can someone give me a list of the keys so I know what I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 5):

1. **In the flying feather room** [image: key in flying feather room]
2. **The bumblebee event when entering the lock room** [image: bumblebee event in lock room]
3. **The ["Osmos" room](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/63272/21177) with the red cell** [image: "Osmos" room]
4. **The resonant brown tadpole room** [image: Resonant things] [image: Inside the brown tadpole]
5. **The ["spiny/urchin" room](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/63471/21177)** [image: "spiny/urchin" room]